# wrong namespace? xsl:template don't find match

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, match

I feel so ashamed about this question, but I can't find a solution, and I hope you can help me.

This is my code xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:/Program%20Files/XML%20Copy%20Editor/esercizi%20xml/prova2.xsl"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
<teiHeader>
    <fileDesc>
        <titleStmt>
            <title></title>
        </titleStmt>
        <publicationStmt><p>AA</p></publicationStmt>
        <sourceDesc><p>AA</p></sourceDesc>
    </fileDesc>
</teiHeader>
    <text>
    <body><div>
    <head>Titolo</head>
        <p>Scriver&#242; un <rs>nome</rs> di luogo come questo:  <rs key="Persia" type="luogo">Persia</rs>.</p>
    </div></body>
    </text>
</TEI>
```

and this is what I wrote in my file xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0">  
    <xsl:template match="/">  
        <back>
            <div>
               <xsl:value-of select="//rs"/>
            </div>
        </back>     
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<back xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <div/>
</back>
```

I don't understand where is my error; I suppose it is in the [namespace](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp), but I can't find the solution.

Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <div> 
           <xsl:value-of select="//rs"/> 
        </div>
```

The expression in the "select" attribute tries to select any `rs` element that is in "no namespace" and there is none such -- nothing is selected.

**You actually want**:

```
        <div> 
           <xsl:value-of select="//tei:rs"/> 
        </div>
```

This in XSLT 1.0, however, outputs only the first selected `rs` element.

**If you want all of them, use something like this**:

```
        <div> 
          <xsl:for-each select="//tei:rs">
           <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
          </xsl:for-each> 
        </div>
```